# SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor - Configure to autowire by name instead of by type?

Tags: java, spring, ejb-3.0, autowired

I'm using a `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor` in an EJB3 stateless session bean, as described in the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch22s03.html#ejb-implementation-ejb3).

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)    // Allows spring injection for its setter methods
public class MyClassImpl extends MyAbstractClass implements MyClass 
{
    ....
    @Autowired
    public void setMyCustomService2(MyService svc) {
        this.service = svc;
    }
```

And in SpringConfig.xml:

```
<bean id="myCustomService1" class="...MyService"/>
<bean id="myCustomService2" class="...MyService"/>
```

When Spring tries to autowire this I get

```
No unique bean of type [...MyService ] is defined: 
  expected single matching bean but found 2: [myCustomService1 , myCustomService2]
```

Unfortunately, it seems EJB autowiring defaults to `byType` mode, and I can't find a way to change it to `byName` mode.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried with a `Qualifier`?

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myCustomService1")
    public void setMyCustomService2(MyService svc) {
    this.service = svc;
}
```